# jobtracker.info could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

Hadoop encounter error when starting.The follows is log info of JobTracker:

```
2015-06-03 09:38:26,106 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /tmp/hadoop-hadooptest/mapred/system/jobtracker.info could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:2091)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:795)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:587)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1428)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1426)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1113)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:62)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.locateFollowingBlock(DFSClient.java:3779)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSClient.java:3639)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.access$2600(DFSClient.java:2842)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSClient.java:3082)
```

continue the above:

```
 
2015-06-03 09:38:26,107 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient: Error Recovery for null bad datanode[0] nodes == null
2015-06-03 09:38:26,107 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient: Could not get block locations. Source file "/tmp/hadoop-hadooptest/mapred/system/jobtracker.info" - Aborting...
2015-06-03 09:38:26,107 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker: Writing to file hdfs://172.18.11.9:9000/tmp/hadoop-hadooptest/mapred/system/jobtracker.info failed!
2015-06-03 09:38:26,107 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker: FileSystem is not ready yet!
2015-06-03 09:38:26,130 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker: Failed to initialize recovery manager.
```

The disk space is enough, and I have closed the firewall, this is result:

```
[hadooptest@hw009 logs]$ chkconfig iptables --list
iptables        0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
```

That's why? How can I resolve this problem? thanks a lots.

There are methods I have try, but couldn't resolve the provlem.

[enter link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14246957/hadoop-tasktracker-issue)

[enter link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25135200/java-io-ioexception-file-tmp-hadoop-eo-mapred-system-jobtracker-info-could-onl)

[enter link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24766759/amazon-ec2-cluster-with-hadoop-file-could-only-be-replicated-to-0-nodes-inst)

Answer (score 0):

I have resolve the problem.I used the commond `bin/start-all.sh` to start hadoop cluster.But now I run the commond `bin/start-dfs.sh` firstly, and then run the commond `bin/start-mapred.sh` after 5 minutes.

I think maybe my server is too old, so start the HDFS need a long time.When HDFS really running, start the mapred system would not encounter the problem.